# How to invert rows and columns using a T-SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that returns one row. However, I want to invert the rows and columns, meaning show the rows as columns and columns as rows. I think the best way to do this is to use a pivot table, which I am no expert in.

Here is my simple query:

```
SELECT Period1, Period2, Period3
FROM GL.Actuals
WHERE Year = 2009 AND Account = '001-4000-50031'
```

> Results (with headers):
>
> Period1, Period2, Period3
>
> 612.58, 681.36, 676.42

I would like for the results to look like this:

> Desired Results:
>
> Period, Amount
>
> Jan, 612.58
>
> Feb, 681.36
>
> Mar, 676.42

This is a simple example, but what I'm really after is a bit more comlex than this. I realize I could produce theses results by using several SELECT commands instead. I'm just hoping someone can shine some light on how to accomplish this with a Pivot Table or if there is yet a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (tested on MSSQL2008):

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE(Period1 Decimal(5, 2), Period2 Decimal(5, 2), Period3 Decimal(5, 2))
INSERT @Data
VALUES (612.58, 681.36, 676.42)

SELECT Period, Amount
FROM (SELECT Period1 AS Jan, Period2 AS Feb, Period3 AS Mar FROM @Data) AS D
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Period IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)) AS U
```

**Update**

Based on Jeff's comment, how about this:

```
DECLARE @Actuals TABLE(Account INT, [Year] INT, Period1 Decimal(5, 2), Period2 Decimal(5, 2), Period3 Decimal(5, 2))
INSERT @Actuals VALUES (1, 2010, 612.58, 681.36, 676.42)
INSERT @Actuals VALUES (1, 2009, 512.58, 581.36, 576.42)

SELECT Account, Period, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT a.Account, a.Period1 AS Jan, a.Period2 AS Feb, a.Period3 AS Mar, a1.Period1 AS Jan1, a1.Period2 AS Feb1, a1.Period3 AS Mar1
    FROM @Actuals AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Actuals AS a1 ON a.Account = a1.Account AND a1.[Year] = a.[Year] - 1
    WHERE a.[Year] = 2010
) AS d
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Period IN (Jan, Feb, Mar, Jan1, Feb1, Mar1)) AS u
```

or, with an explicit year column:

```
DECLARE @Actuals TABLE(Account INT, [Year] INT, Period1 Decimal(5, 2), Period2 Decimal(5, 2), Period3 Decimal(5, 2))
INSERT @Actuals VALUES (1, 2010, 612.58, 681.36, 676.42)
INSERT @Actuals VALUES (1, 2009, 512.58, 581.36, 576.42)

SELECT Account, [Year], Period, Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT a.Account, a.[Year], a.Period1 AS Jan, a.Period2 AS Feb, a.Period3 AS Mar
    FROM @Actuals AS a WHERE a.[Year] IN (2009, 2010)
) AS d
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Period IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)) AS u
```

Comment: This is a great solution for the simple example I gave. However, if I need to include another column then I don't see how I can do it this way. See example below. I am doing the JOIN for the other column, but can't get it.

SELECT Account, Period, [2010 Actual]
FROM (
 SELECT a.Account
 , a.Period1 AS Jan, a.Period2 AS Feb, a.Period3 AS Mar
 , a1.Period1 AS Jan1, a1.Period2 AS Feb1, a1.Period3 AS Mar1
 FROM GL.Actuals a
 LEFT JOIN GL.Actuals a1 ON a1.Account = a.Account AND a1.Year = a.Year - 1
 WHERE a.Year = 2010) AS d
UNPIVOT ([2010 Actual] FOR Period IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)) AS u

Comment: Interesting, but not exactly what I'm after. In this case I need two amount columns, one for each year.

Comment: in that case, after the unpivot, apply a pivot like this: SELECT Account, Period, [2009], [2010] FROM (...) AS DP PIVOT (MAX(Amount) FOR [Year] IN ([2009], [2010])) AS P, where ... is the last unpivot from above. hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed set of fields, you can use a UNION of select statements, each statement fetching one of the fields. Standard SQL does not provide a way to transpose the result for a variable number of fields, e.g. `select  * from table`.

If MSSQL has an extension which helps (like pivot), I don't know about it.

Comment: Thanks, Alison. :)
Is it part of some version of the SQL standard or an extension?

Comment: Pivote tables are part of Transact-SQL, which is unique to SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Check the unnest function, its quite amazing with little overhead. Just add a select query on top of the nested select query and unnest at that point:

```
SELECT id,
   unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c']) AS colname,
   unnest(array[a, b, c]) AS thing
FROM foo
ORDER BY id;
```